# Is it possible to read Full name using 1 string Variable in C file management?

Tags: c

This C program is Ok if single word name is used. Actually I tried to make a text file reader that can store data in structure variable. And after that i will sum how many day they attended. But I am facing a issue when I use full name. My code is given below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    int serial;
    int roll;
    char name[210];
    int day1,day2;
};

main()
{
    struct student read;
    FILE *fp2;

    fp2 = fopen("student_file.txt","r");
    if(fp2==NULL)
      printf("Not find");
    while(fscanf(fp2,"%d. %d %s %d %d",&read.serial,&read.roll,read.name,&read.day1,&read.day2)==5)
    {
      fprintf(stdout,"%d %d %s %d %d\n",read.serial,read.roll,read.name,read.day1,read.day2);
    }
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

This txt file can read easily.

```
1. 123 Nahid 1 1
2. 465 Zahid 1 0
3. 789 Sahid 1 1
4. 159 Mahid 1 0
```

But I want to read a text file using fscanf and fprintf.

```
5. 889 Mark Joe 1 0
6. 669 M. J. Rakib 1 0
```

Is it possible to read full name using file management in c?
It will helpful to me if I can read only 1 line at least.

Comment: `"%s"` read a space delimited string, ie it is impossible to read `"John Smith"` with `"%s"` because of the space. Better is to use `fgets()` for all user input (even if it comes from a file ibstead of the usual keyboard).

Comment: if you provide me a sample, it will help me to understand how to store two or more word in one string as a name variable .

Comment: If you put the fixed-width fields at the start, then the name and the end of the line; then it would be very easy to modify `fscanf` to read until the end-of-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible supposing a name cannot contains digits (personalty I never see a name having) just modify the *fscanf* format to use :

```
"%d. %d %209[^0-9] %d %d"
```

`209`is here to not take the risk to write out of the array in case the name is too long

because extra spaces are saved at the end of the name you need to remove them, as you can see if I print with that format :

```
"%d %d '%s' %d %d\n"
```

producing

```
1 123 'Nahid ' 1 1
2 465 'Zahid ' 1 0
3 789 'Sahid ' 1 1
4 159 'Mahid ' 1 0
5 889 'Mark Joe ' 1 0
6 669 'M. J. Rakib ' 1 0
```

---

Warning in your code if you cannot open the file you will execute the `while` so you call `fscanf` then `fclose` on NULL with an undefined behavior